# Is it possible to motion track footage from an iPhone SE?

Tags: tracking

I cannot find sensor width or focal length for the camera in the iPhone SE. Is it possible to motion track footage from this device? And if so, what do I fill these specifications with?

Extra:
In my research I found the following.
If  it helps, the iPhone SE and 6s use the Sony RGBW IMX315 12MP BSI sensor.
The sensor size is 1/3″ (4.80 x 3.60 mm). I'm unsure which is the width, but one of these two numbers has to be it. That leaves me with the last detail, the focal length.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I don't own that device, if you could provide a sample video we'll be able to take a few test on the footage (remember to provide enough parallax and feature points). You should be able to get the focal lenght from the camera solver, aong with K1 and K2 if the tracking has been succesful.

Comment: For that camera model the focal lenght is 4mm, that corresponds to 29mm for full frame sensors (36x24mm).